# Using custom comparator for std::set with custom constructor

Tags: c++, stl

Let's say I have a class

```
class Custom
{
public:
    Custom (int x, int y) : x (x), y (x) {} 
    bool operator() (int a, int b)
    {
        return a < x && y < b;
    }
private:
    int x, y;
};
```

And I want a set that is

```
std::set<int, Custom> s
```

with Custom's custom constructor (i.e. Custom (1, 2))

How can I achieve this?

In addition, if I want to use this in an unordered_map, such as

```
std::unordered_map<string, std::set<int, Custom>> ht
```

how can I do this?

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a00bfa07eb4c50f6

Comment: I should point out here that your custom comparator (which I'm sure is just an example, not really what you were planning on using) does not impose a strict weak ordering on the integers, and so will lead to undefined behavior in your set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Making the set

You need to provide the comparer when you construct the set:

```
using std::unordered_map;
using std::set; 
using std::string; 

set<int, Custom> s(Custom(10, 20)); 
// Or: 
auto s = set<int, Custom>(Custom(10, 20));
```

This is because it needs to have a comparer as soon as you start assigning elements to the set, and because your comparer has parameters, it needs to know what those are

#### Using the set in a map

The comparer has to be default-constructible because calling `map["key"]` will default-construct the element if it doesn't exist:

```
class Custom
{
   public:
    // Add a default constructor
    Custom() : x(0), y(0) {}
    Custom (int x, int y) : x (x), y (x) {} 
    bool operator() (int a, int b)
    {
        return a < x && y < b;
    }
   private:
    int x, y;
};
```

In this case, it's OK to provide a default constructor to the comparer because we can reassign it:

```
unordered_map<string, set<int, Custom>> map; 
map["some key"] = set<int, Custom>(Custom(10, 20));
```

#### What if I don't or can't have a default constructor?

We can still use `unordered_map`, but we have to use `map.at("key")` and `map.emplace("key", value)` instead of `map["key"]`:

```
unordered_map<string, set<int, Custom>> map; 
set<int, Custom> s(Custom(10, 20)); 
set<int, Custom> s2(Cunstom(30, 40)); 
s2.insert(1);
s2.insert(2); 
s2.insert(3); // put some stuff in the set

map.emplace("Hello", s); //Inserts the set

map.insert({"Hello", s2}); //Inserts the set as a key-value pair
```

We can get values using `map.at`:

```
// This line gets the set at "Hello", and inserts 10 into the set:
map.at("Hello").insert(10); 
// If "Hello" isn't in the map, there's an error
```

And we can check if something's in the map by using `map.find("key")`:

```
// Get an iterator to the key value pair held by "Hello" in the map:
// An iterator acts like a pointer
auto iterator = map.find("Hello"); 

if(iterator == map.end()) // Check if we found the thing
{
    std::cout << "Couldn't find 'Hello' in the map"; 
} 
else 
{
    // Get the key from the iterator
    string key = iterator->first; 
    // Get a reference to the value from the iterator
    set<int, Custom>& value = iterator->second; 

}
```

Comment: Also, Custom does not satisfy the [compare requirements](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Compare)

Answer (score 1):

`std::set` has an overloaded constructor that takes an instance of the comparator class as a parameter. If the comparator class does not have a default constructor, as is the case here, you must use that constructor to construct each instance of a `std::set`:

```
std::set<int, Custom> set_instance{ Custom{4,4} };
```

This instance of the `std::set` uses `Custom{4,4}` as its comparator. Different instances of this set can use different comparators.

Because this `std::set` does not have a default constructor, you cannot use the map's `[]` operator, so you will have to do a little bit work. `[]` will attempt to default-construct an instance of the value class, and this set no longer has a usable default constructor; so you will need to use `find()` or `insert()` to explicitly search for, and/or insert new values into the map. C++17 adds an `insert_or_assign()` method that makes this a little bit easier.